# SSH fingerprint difference

Tags: networking, router, ssh, security, modem

**tl,dr:**

> - The user has a home server accessed via SSH by them and their coworkers. Recently, coworkers began experiencing connection issues, encountering different SSH keys than expected.
> - The user, on the local network, does not experience these issues due to possible NAT loopback.
> - They discovered that the coworkers are seeing a Dropbear SSH server, not the expected OpenSSH, suggesting the modem/router is interfering.
> - The modem/router RTF8115VW, supplied by the ISP, does not have easily adjustable settings, leading to uncertainty about potential hacking/security breaches or configuration issues.
> - The user seeks advice on the next steps.

**Full thing:**

I have a server at home which I connect to via SSH (local network) and my coworkers also access it via SSH (internet) directly through my IP.

A few days ago, my coworkers started having connection problems, with the terminal complaining that the public key was not the same. We started investigating.

I found that when accessing via the local network, I saw the same fingerprint that the server reports if I connect directly to it, starting with `yury4`. This happens even if I access my external IP: it seems that the modem/router does some kind of NAT loopback translation, and everything works. However, my coworkers see another fingerprint, starting with `XyTk/`, consistently, and can no longer connect.

Observing a little more, we noticed that they saw a different SSH server being reported: Dropbear. What I saw was OpenSSH. Upon investigating, I discovered that Dropbear seems ideal for embedded systems, which led me to suspect the modem/router. Bingo: if I ask the modem/router what its fingerprint is, it responds with the one starting with `XyTk/`.

The problem is that I can't identify what's happening. My basic understanding is that the modem/router should not mess with packets, just pass them on, right? I also don't know how to fix the problem. The modem/router is from the access provider, and some settings do not seem accessible. In fact, I don't even know if this little thing has been invaded and whether there is a man-in-the-middle happening, or if it's just a configuration issue.

What would be the next diagnosis step be?

EDIT: the device is a RTF8115VW.

Comment: Is SSH enabled on your router, most routers that support it, have it disabled by default and most certainly don’t allow external clients to the network to connect by default

Comment: @Ramhound I tried to check the router for any ssh setting and found nothing. It's a RTF8115VW. I set it to forward port 22, though.

Comment: If you are port forwarding port 22 then it’s impossible for it to be receiving or handling the SSH traffic on that port.

Comment: (1) Did you open the port 22 to the internet for your coworker? Or has it been a different one? (2) In the latter case: Did your coworker choose the the correct port to access your server? // If the port question is not the point, (3) did the port-forwarding fail? Has it been reset/reconfigured somehow, so the connection ends at the router? (4) Has the port changed, but the forwarding of the port has not been updated, too?

Comment: @dodrg I opened port 22 and redirected it to the server's internal IP. And it worked nicely for more than two years. It's mysteriously changed in the last few days.

Comment: @Ramhound I suspect it might be hacked.

Comment: @FernandoD'Andrea - There is no evidence the unit has been hacked. If you are concerned, then request the unit be reset by your ISP. However, I have serious doubts, the correct information is being used as what much more likely is your IP address has simply changed. It's also impossible, in my opinion, to be attempting to log into the router because you have port forwarding enabled. I have doubts SSH is even enabled on the router, most routers, don't support it and must be explicitly enabled. In additional to being explicitly enabled you have to allow traffic from outside your network to login

Comment: Can you show the redirection / "port forwarding" rule that you have set up?

Comment: @Ramhound Why would you doubt there's SSH in the modem if I can actually connect to it and access some sort of simple shell? And it reports a fingerprint.

Comment: @u1686_grawity Name: "Port Mapping pinhole (by USER_INTERFACE): CPE-SSH ", Protocol: UDP/TCP,  local port: 22:22, local ip: xx.xx.xx.xx/32 (the server's internal ip), remote port: 22:22, remote ip: *, rule: allow remote.

Comment: @FernandoD'Andrea - So the server you are attempting to access is RTF8115VW and not some other device on the network? Because your question does not make it clear the device you are able to connect to is actually the RTF8115VW.  I thought the entire problem is that clients outside of your network, you suspect, are accessing the RTF8115VW instead of the actual server they are attempting to access

Answer (score 1):

It might be a nice research to find the reasons. But what you are writing suspects to me that you possibly have been hacked.

So ask yourself what are the primary things to do in such a case.

1. If you have nothing to loose, you can do some nice forensics and investigations about the how and where of the noticed problems.
2. If there is something of importance, you should think about isolation and immediate backup but not touching any existing backup media. — Worst case is that currently a ransomware is silently encrypting your files and will popup in a few hours or days to ask for money.
3. A not so aggressive scenario is that the router has become a part of a botnet and is accessible for the bad guys by a fingertip to do some nasty things to other websites.

##### Why do I take a hack into account?

- The first remarkable hint is, that you opened the SSH standard port to the Internet side.
  My opinion: At an all-in-one router, *never ever* do this to a standard port for SSH or any other network service. – If (within this router or the server you forward to) there is any implementation bug or a configuration bug, they'll get you hacked. At least the standard ports are continuously scanned by the bad guys, day and night, worldwide, fully automated, like a never ending rain.
- The problem popped up some time after it regularly worked. So why should this functionality change?
- The ssh daemon of the router obviously is serving the internet side. (Or the port forwarding does not end at the server but at the router. But why?) This happened out of a sudden and you even do not know how to enable the ssh port of the router.

As you (and your coworker) say you didn't change anything (are you sure?) one of these things have to be taken into account:

1. a firmware- or configuration-update of the router could have been erroneous.
2. a service technician of the internet provider has misconfigured  something.
3. a hack has happened.

I would take the worst case scenario an would be happy if it proves false.

##### What next?

Doublecheck, that the Dropbear is really hosted on the router. Depending on the truth of this statement, the whole scenario can change.

If true:

I would suspect your router and your server as being compromised (at least) and someone unauthorized opened the ssh port.

###### Gather information

1. If you can and want to do some traffic analysis, do it now, then disconnect your systems from the internet.
2. Check the logs (router, server, clients) for suspicious entries (but they might have been manipulated), especially at the time span, the functionality changed.
3. Check your data and installations.

###### Elimiate potential risks

To consult some professional tools like malware checkers would be a good idea.

- If not yet done, disconnect the internet.
- Do some emergency backup (not using the regular backup media but keeping them offline)
- Reset your router and preferably install (reinstall) the firmware. More you hardly can do against backdoors.
  *You may copy the router configuration, but DO NOT "save configuration" and after reset "restore configuration by file". You possibly would reapply some unwanted settings.*
- Think about what to do with your server. By the port forwarding the potential hacker had direct contact to it, possibly hacking it first and then compromising the whole LAN.
- Think and decide about the possible risk that your clients might be compromised (including your coworker's client!).

###### After the reset, some things to think about

- Check the router for the open ssh port at the Internet side and LAN side, before you apply your personal configuration. Be sure to find out, how this can be enabled/disabled.
- If you require external ssh-access for your coworker choose an uncommon port, preferably between 10000 and 65535, not using "22" within the number.
- Be sure what you are configuring. Just acting on *"oh it happens to work now"* is a bad idea. — Clean up accurately the trial and error remains.
- Think about a real firewall that isolates your internet accessible servers from your LAN.
- Harden your server as it is exposed to the internet
- If you have to use a Dynamic DNS provider, do not choose a service provided from your router manufacturer. This is a honeypot for hardware specific hacks.
- To disconnect from the hacker's database choose a different DNS-name. If you've a fixed external IP-address, opt to change it, if possible.

Answer (score 1):

> The problem is that I can't identify what's happening. My basic understanding is that the modem/router should not mess with packets, just pass them on, right?

Well, not exactly.

For one, while it's true that routers *normally* do not mess with packets at or above IP level (aside from decrementing IP TTL), you also have NAT in addition to plain routing, and NAT is literally a form of "messing with packets" as it involves rewriting of both L3 (IP) and L4 (TCP/UDP) headers. (And that's even before we get into ALGs aka "NAT helpers" – e.g. routers actually rewrite FTP *commands and responses* to make it work via NAT…)

But in your case it's not the messing with packets but the *lack thereof* that's causing the differences:

- Recall that when you're connecting from the outside, you're connecting to the *router's* public IP address. When the "port redirect" rule is active (which is basically DNAT), the router rewrites each packet's "destination IP" field before passing them on (so that they would be routed to the server's internal IP address).
- When the "port redirect" rule is *not* active, however, nothing is rewritten – so if you connect to the router's IP address, you are really just connecting to… the router.

It's fairly normal for the router to have its own SSH server. Usually, though, external connections are both 1) denied by the router's regular firewall rules and 2) overridden by the "port redirect" DNAT rule so that the router never even considers them as inbound. But in your case, it sounds very much like neither of those rules are working correctly – the DNAT rewriting is not happening *and* the firewall filter isn't blocking the inbound connection.

So if I had to guess (based on the fact that internal "NAT loopback" *does* appear to work), it's some kind of configuration issue – maybe the ISP deploying a new config overnight – which causes both the filter and NAT rules to expect a different interface as the "ingress interface". (For example, maybe the WAN interface is eth0.3 but the rules expect WAN to be eth0.4...)

- Check whether it goes away after rebooting the router, or deleting and re-adding the port redirect rule.
- Check if it still happens if you set up port-redirect for a different port than the usual. (It won't fix the issue
- Since the router is locked down by the ISP, it's really the ISP's problem; call their tech support, ask them for a replacement router or something.